# How to remove toolbar created by eclipse 4 application wizard (RCP)

Tags: eclipse-rcp, toolbar

When i create an eclipse 4 application using the wizard it automatically creates these default toolbar and menus.
It seems that whatever i do they just stay there. 
I cannot modify them and the only thing that works is modifying the handler's code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the workspace is not updated for some reason so what i did is marked the "clear workspace data" checkbox on the launch config and it is solved